# When I edit a web part it shows twice! SharePoint2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development

I have a webpart created with visual webpart, it has a GridView and it looks like as following image:

[image: Visual Web Part]

For everytime I edit the page containing this webpart it duplicates I.E if I edit this webpart 2time it shows me 4 tables just like the following image: 
[image]

But This thing happens only in editing mode, but sometimes the whole web part disappears!

Thanks in Advice.

Comment: Sound like your webpart is not handling `Postbacks` very well.. Not easy to help you without the relevant source code

Comment: Are you adding the columns programmatically every time the page reloads?

Comment: @RobertLindgren You can Check my update question to show code

Comment: @ErinL Yes I am creating columns programatically

Comment: Not seeing your code, but make sure to do a `if(!Page.IsPostBack){` around the code creating your grid. In your case around all code in the `Page_Load` method

Comment: @RobertLindgren check it again I have added it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your webpart is behaving like this because your are not handling postbacks correctly. Wrap all code in the `Page_Load` method with the following

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack){ 
    // Original code here
}
```

Some info about `PostBack` here: http://net-informations.com/faq/asp/ispostback.htm

Or, just before your new databinding of the grid do this

```
GridView1.DataSource = null;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

so it will be

```
GridView1.DataSource = null;
GridView1.DataBind();

GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
GridView1.DataBind();
```

This question is really an ASP.net question and not SharePoint specific to be fair. It's about understanding the lifecycle of ASP.net pages

Comment: It is not duplicating anymore but unpredictably it disappears

Comment: It is working perfectly thank you so much you are a life saver thanks

Comment: What part made it work? Only the post back check?

Comment: the first and the second part of answer!